# Error de Sintxis al ejecutar un INSERT INTO en base de datos Accesde desde excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, macos

tengo un libro de Excel que ejecuta via VBA varias consultas y modificaciones a una base de datos de Microsoft Access.

Hasta ahora tenia este código y funcionaba bien:

```
Sub Conexión (BD)
BD = "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\EdificioBD.accdb"
End Sub

Sub Insrt_Factagua()

Dim X As Integer
Dim Und As String, Num As String, Piso As String, FECHA As String, Ant As String, Act As String, Prom As String, Mont As String, Lt As String, SQL As String
Dim Rs As Recordset
Dim Con As Connection
Dim MES As String, Ano As String

Set Rs = New Recordset
Set Con = New Connection

Call Conexion(BD)
Con.Open BD

'-Limpiar para sobreescribir-------------------
MES = Month(FRINICIO.AguaTextBox1.Value)
Ano = Year(FRINICIO.AguaTextBox1.Value)

SQL = "Delete FROM AGUA WHERE (MES =" & MES & ") AND (AÑO=" & Ano & ")"


Rs.Open SQL, Con

Set Rs = Nothing
Set Rs = New Recordset


For X = 1 To 17

Und = "'" & FRINICIO.Controls("Label" & X).Caption & "'"
Num = "'" & FRINICIO.Controls("Label" & X + 17).Caption & "'"
Piso = "'" & FRINICIO.Controls("Label" & X + 34).Caption & "'"
FECHA = "'" & FRINICIO.Controls("AGUATEXTBOX" & X) & "'"
Ant = "'" & CDbl(FRINICIO.Controls("AGUATEXTBOX" & X + 17)) & "'"
Act = "'" & CDbl(FRINICIO.Controls("AGUATEXTBOX" & X + 34)) & "'"
Prom = "'" & CDbl(FRINICIO.Controls("AGUATEXTBOX" & X + 68)) & "'"
Mont = "'" & CDbl(FRINICIO.TextPE) & "'"
Lt = "'" & CDbl(FRINICIO.TextLT) & "'"

SQL = "Insert into AGUA (UNIDAD,No,PISO,FECHA,ANTERIOR,ACTUAL,COPROMEDIO,MontAgua,Litros) values(" _
& Und & "," & Num & "," & Piso & "," & FECHA & "," & Ant & "," & Act & "," & Prom & "," & Mont & "," & Lt & ");"


Rs.Open SQL, Con

Next

Set Con = Nothing
Set Rs = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Pero ahora trabajo desde MAC, así que instalé parallels para poder usar Access, y el problema es que la conexión que tenia no funcionaba, por lo que la cambié por:

```
'****Nueva conexión compatible con windows 11 arm (mac parallels 18)
BD = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\EdificioBD.accdb"
```

Pues ahora me funciona todo bien excepto esta parte de código, que me da error de sintaxis en INSERT INTO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo raro es que tengo otras instrucciones de INSERT INTO que no dan error, y son exactamente iguales, como esta:

```
Sub Agg_Emp()


'Agregar empleados
Dim Nm As String, PTO As String, SQL As String, COD As String, Car As String
Dim Rs As Recordset
Dim Con As Connection
Dim SAL As Double
Dim BONOANT As Double
Dim BONOAL As Double
Dim OTROS As Double

Set Rs = New Recordset
Set Con = New Connection

Call Conexion(BD)
Con.Open BD


Nm = "'" & UCase(FREMPLEADOS.NOM.Text) & "'"
PTO = "'" & UCase(FREMPLEADOS.PTO.Text) & "'"
COD = "'" & UCase(FREMPLEADOS.CODIGO.Text) & "'"
Car = "'" & UCase(FREMPLEADOS.CARNET.Text) & "'"
SAL = FREMPLEADOS.SALARIO.Value
BONOANT = FREMPLEADOS.BONOANT.Value
BONOAL = FREMPLEADOS.BONOAL.Value
OTROS = FREMPLEADOS.OTROS.Value

SQL = "Insert into EMPLEADOS (NOMBRES,PUESTO,CODIGO,CARNET,SALARIOS,BONOANTI,BONOALIM,OTROS) values(" _
& Nm & "," & PTO & "," & COD & "," & Car & "," & SAL & "," & BONOANT & "," & BONOAL & "," & OTROS & ")"


Rs.Open SQL, Con

Set Con = Nothing
Set Rs = Nothing

MsgBox "Nuevo empleado agregado correctamente!", vbInformation, "AVISO!"

End Sub
```

Alguna idea??

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Nunca pongas código como imagen.  En cualquier caso, la que te da error tiene punto y coma al final, prueba a ver si es eso. no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: INSERT INTO  o DELETE se utilizan con el método Execute y no con el método Open. Open se utiliza para extraer/consultar datos pero no para modificar una tabla añadiendo, eliminando o actualizando datos.